# Is there a maintainable way to install a recent version of phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, phpmyadmin

We use phpMyAdmin on a couple of servers running Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu ships with PHP 7.2, the latest phpMyAdmin version from the official repositories is 4.6.6, which is not compatible with PHP 7.2.

phpMyAdmin does not seem to have an official package repository, all repositories I have found seem not to serve the latest version either.

The only workarounds I have found so far:

- Installing PHP 7.1 in addition to PHP 7.2 from `ppa:ondrej/php` and have phpMyAdmin use the older version
- Manually overwriting the phpMyAdmin files that come with the official package with the latest files

Both seem to be problematic in terms of maintaining the software on the servers. I was wondering how others solve this problem.

Comment: Make your own fresh packages.

Comment: I suppose it comes down to your definition of the word "maintainable". Do you want the vendor (PHP directly or Ubuntu the distribution) to maintain it, or are you willing to maintain it?

Comment: I might have phrased this badly. I was interested in best practices concerning latest versions of phpMyAdmin, while still being able to have stable production systems (which are secure, upgradeable, etc.). I was that others have found practical solutions to the compatibility problems.

Comment: "stable" is only a word which means all packages were tested by thousand of users and nobody notices any errors/bugs. When you install a non-tested new version of any program, then your distro is not 100% stable anymore by definition.

Answer (score 1):

If Ubuntu is shipping packages that are not compatible with each other, that is a bug.  [It has apparently been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1767361), but unfortunately there is not yet an official fix.

PHP does have its own packaging system, [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org), if you want to try and use that instead of system packages as PHPMyAdmin [seems to maintain composer packages](https://packagist.org/packages/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin).